# Cannot build a newly created project (Hamburger Template)

Tags: mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal, template10

I just installed Template10 Extension on Visual Studio 2015 Community. When I create a new UWP project with the Hamburger or Minimal Template, I get the following error.

"The name 'PropertyChanged_ViewModel' does not exist in the current context"

Blank Template from the same extension works fine though.

Yes, I have updated all the extensions to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the error. Check this [pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/pull/1045).

Going by the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), The BindingMode of TextBlock element defaults to OneWay and so there is no need to specify it explicitly. All you need to is, Open DetailsPage.xaml and find the following line

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Value, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=DesigntimeValue}" />
```

and replace it with this

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Value, FallbackValue=DesigntimeValue}" />
```

Comment: That just doesn't make sense. DetailPageViewModel implements INPC through the ViewModelBase. https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Templates%20(Project)/Hamburger/ViewModels/DetailPageViewModel.cs#L13